# Postgres Insert: Use newly inserted row's id in another column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I am designing a table with audit trailing based on the architecture in this article:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105768/Audit-Trail-Tracing-Data-Changes-in-Database

The gist of it is that when you update a row, you just insert a copy of the current row then update the row so you have a history of the states of the data at points in time. Here is an example from the article of what the table looks like:

[image]

My question is about the very first insert. When inserting the first row, I need to mark the original_id the same as the id of the row. Can I do that in one statement? Or do I have to insert the new row first then update the original_id column with the new id.

As per the example picture, this is what the insert statement would look like:

```
begin;

insert into people (status, name, created_date, created_by)
values ('active', 'Julia Singleton', 'today', 'me')
returning id;

// use the returned id to update original_id on the row
// ...

commit;
```

I'm curious if this can be done in 1 statement.

Comment: You need to provide the code you are using for the insert.

Comment: @GordonLinoff added an example sql statement for you.

Comment: WHy not just leave original ID is null when it's the original record?

Comment: @Twelfth that's a possibility. It just opens the small chance of forgetting to set the original_id on a history record, but I supposed that could mitigated by using a stored procedure to update the row instead of application code. This question was more out of curiosity to see if this was possible

Comment: I'd go with Original ID is null when it's the original and coalesce(original_id,id) whenever you refer to the original ID in either selects or updates (that sees the null and returns the ID of the original record).  Less updates in a DB is good.  Don't think you can do this as one statement...curious though, Gordon surprises me a lot.

Comment: I'd make a separate history table rather than lumping your history in your main table. Your main table will become larger than it needs to be and queries will have more data to sift through. Moving it to a separate table keeps the data in the table to the minimum number of records

Answer (score 2):

Using the example shown by the OP, you can specify a `default` value for `original_id` column to be the current value of the sequence responsible for generating the `id` - if it's set up as [`serial`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) or [`identity` column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-PARMS-GENERATED-IDENTITY), you can get it dynamically with [`pg_get_serial_sequence()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#id-1.5.8.32.6.3.2.2.15.1.1.1):

```sql
create table people (
  id bigint generated by default as identity primary key,
  original_id bigint not null 
                     default currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"people"', 'id'))
                     references people(id),
  status text, 
  name text, 
  created_date date, 
  created_by text);
```

If the table's already in place, you can also `alter` the column in-place:

```
alter table people alter column original_id
  set default currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"people"', 'id'));
```

Then, when you want `original_id` to default to `id`, you just leave it out the `insert` target column list and it'll be generated the same way `id` would: [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6fCkfcnQ)

```sql
insert into people (status, name, created_date, created_by)
select 'status_'||g,'name_'||g,(-100*random())::int+date'today','created_by_'||g
from generate_series(1,3)_(g)
returning *;
```

| id | original_id | status | name | created_date | created_by |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | status_1 | name_1 | 2023-11-18 | created_by_1 |
| 2 | 2 | status_2 | name_2 | 2023-10-31 | created_by_2 |
| 3 | 3 | status_3 | name_3 | 2023-12-20 | created_by_3 |

Here's how I imagine you'd add another version of a row:

```sql
insert into people (original_id,status, name, created_date, created_by)
select id,status||'_v2', name||'_v2', 'today', created_by
from people where id=3
returning *;
```

| id | original_id | status | name | created_date | created_by |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 3 | status_3_v2 | name_3_v2 | 2024-02-08 | created_by_3 |

Doing that leaves the default insert process unaffected - each row sees the current value of their id-generating sequence. You can also list and assign `id` and `original_id` explicitly:

```sql
insert into people (id, original_id, status, name, created_date, created_by)
values (nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"people"', 'id')),
        currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"people"', 'id')),
        'active', 'Julia Singleton', 'today', 'me')
returning *;
```

---

If you wish to use values that were generated this way in an `insert` statement, you can simply wrap it in a [`with` CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html), then use the output of its [`returning`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#id-1.9.3.152.7) clause as the source for your other statement:

```sql
create table people_salary (
  id bigint generated by default as identity primary key,
  people_id bigint references people(id),
  salary numeric);

insert into people_salary(people_id,salary)
select id,7e4 from people;

with new_versions_of_people as (
  insert into people (original_id, status, name, created_date, created_by)
  select id,'RICH_'||status,'Mr/Mrs_'||name,date'today',created_by||'(lottery)'
  from people where id in (1,7)
  returning id,original_id)
update people_salary
set salary=round(salary^2),
    people_id=new_versions_of_people.id
from new_versions_of_people
where people_id=original_id
returning *;
```

| id | people_id | salary | id | original_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 4900000000 | 8 | 1 |
| 7 | 9 | 4900000000 | 9 | 7 |

Everyone started off with a 70k salary, then you made new, rich versions of 2 people, which you then made actually rich by squaring their salary.

- Note that the outer `returning *` gives you both the full result of the `update`, as well as the `insert..returning` fields it was based on. It's good practice to [alias all these fields adequately](https://dbfiddle.uk/0rcAKnmF) - otherwise, you end up with multiple columns named the same.
- The `select id` refers to the `id` found by `from people where...` that will go into `original_id`. The later `returning id` will refer to the field generated by this insert, because `id` wasn't targeted.
- In the outer `update`, `where people_id=original_id` tells it which row to update *before* it overwrites its value by doing `people_id=new_versions_of_people.id`

Comment: Wow, that's an elaborate answer. What I get from it is that my attempt to use a subquery couldn't work but the inverse process, using WITH, makes it work. I had seen examples for WITH before, but never in combination with UPDATE, and I think I should've been able to figure this out myself, but alas, you made it easier :)